# Inkscape clip and export - clip border visible?

Tags: pdf, gimp, libreoffice-writer, vector-graphics, inkscape

I have a problem with clipping a bitmap in Inkscape.

After I export a clipped bitmap into PNG it looks fine. However after I print this PNG into a PDF file, insert it into LibreOffice writer (and save it into a PDF from there as well) I get a thin grey line where my clip path in Inkscape used to be. If I look carefully at the PNG file using GIMP I see that along the clip path I have a thin line of partially transparent pixels - I guess it can have something to do with it? For clipping I tried paths with 0 width, with no stroke, and it doesn't help. Any help appreciated.

I use Inkscape 0.92pre1 on Ubuntu 14.04.3.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't figured out what was the reason for this, but what helped is having a white background behind my objects, not transparent.